# UIButton setTittle not working in a specific case

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have two views in my app and a plist file to store some values.

In the first view I've created a button called `frequenciesButton` that opens the second view and another button to restore the default values.

In the second view there is a pickerView and a "Done" button.

On the .m of the first view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //
    self.gameSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:gameSettingsFilePath];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self refreshView];
}

- (void)refreshView {

    [self.frequenciesButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ hz and %@ hz", [self.gameSettings objectForKey:@"freq-freq1"], [self.gameSettings objectForKey:@"freq-freq2"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ...

}

- (IBAction)setDefaultValues:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.gameSettings setValue:@880 forKey:@"freq-freq1"];
    [self.gameSettings setValue:@1122 forKey:@"freq-freq2"];
    ...
    [self.gameSettings writeToFile:gameSettingsFilePath atomically:YES];
    [self refreshView];

}
```

When the first view is loaded, the button title is changed to the default values stored in the `gameSettings` dictionary. The method `setTitle:` works.

When I click on the `frequenciesButton` it opens the second view with the pickerView, I select the two new values for the `freq-freq1` and `freq-freq2` and it saves to the plist file on done button.

The problem is that the `frequenciesButton` title is not changed when the second view is dissmissed and the first view appears. The `refreshView` method is called but the button `setTitle:` does not work.

In this case, if I go back one screen, and return to this view, the button title is updated.

And when I click on `defaultValuesButton`, the `frequenciesButton` title changes. The method `setTitle:` also works.

Any ideas of what must be happening?

Comment: Add logging to see whether `self.frequenciesButton` is nil.

Comment: I've put a `NSLog` , tried before and after the `setTitle`, in the `refreshView` method, and it always return a UIButton. The log: `<UIButton: 0x7ae9fc60; frame = (244 85; 180 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae9fd80>>`

Comment: I have made a small test project using the same logic of my app: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ev91zgz06xsu9qj/UIButtonTest.zip?dl=0). And I got the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HaHA! I love that you added a link to your project.

SO!! The problem was that you have separate properties in each view to hold the data from the saved plist file, `self.settings`. This is fine, don't mesh them together. The requirement you had to do with this, when switching views, is to keep the ivar or properties updated as the data updates too :D

Here is how I fixed the problem:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
    [self updateView];

}
```

I checked out the file and that was updated, but the dictionary in the `TestViewController.h` was not updated

I hope this was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem there, not sure if it will fix it, is the fact that you have used ViewWillAppear incorrectly, you have this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self refreshView];
}
```

but it should be this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self refreshView];
}
```

You need to invoke "[super viewWillAppear:animated];" or you will have side effects, fix that first and see what happens.